# List of Dynamic Strings to Map

Tags: java, list, dictionary, java-8, java-stream

Is there an efficient way to convert the below List to List of Map? I'm looking for an optimized solution using Java Streams. Your help is much appreciated.

`List<String>`:

```
[
    "src/main/java/com/abc.java",
    "68",
    "src/main/java/com/def.java",
    "21",
    "src/main/java/com/ghi.java",
    "4",
    "9",
    "58,3",
    "61,0",
    "src/main/java/com/jkl.java",
    "3",
    "12",
    "src/main/java/com/mno.java",
    "8,0",
    "13",
    "40,5",
    "48,2",
    "61,5"
]
```

`List<Map<String, List<String>>>`:

```
[{
        "src/main/java/com/abc.java": ["68"]
    },
    {
        "src/main/java/com/def.java": ["21"]
    },
    {
        "src/main/java/com/ghi.java": ["4", "9", "58", "59", "60"]
    },
    {
        "src/main/java/com/jkl.java": ["3", "12"]
    },
    {
        "src/main/java/com/mno.java": ["13", "40", "41", "42", "43", "44", "48", "49", "61", "62", "63", "64", "65"]
    }
]
```

Comment: Have you made any effort to solve this problem yourself, and, if so, can you include the Java code you have tried?

Comment: Please elaborate a bit more with input and required output with data and code (You already have done).

Comment: *"I'm looking for an optimised solution"* Optimized from what? Do you already have a solution and want help to improve it? Then you should ask on softwareengineering.stackexchange.com with your implementation. Or do you not have a solution yet, and are looking for solutions, but then I don't understand what you mean by "optimized"?

Comment: What makes this list of strings a “List of Dynamic Strings”? Further, you should not require your readers to guess from a single sample, what logic the program ought to have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I highly discourage you from using the [java-stream](/questions/tagged/java-stream) in this case since you are dependant on the previous elements.

```
Map<String, List<String>> o = list.stream()
   .reduce(
        new TreeMap<String, List<String>>(),
        (map,j) -> {
            if (j.startsWith("src")) {
                map.putIfAbsent(j, new ArrayList<>());
            } else {
                map.get(map.lastKey()).add(j);
            }
            return map;},
        (i,j) -> i);
```

As far as you see, the solution has many flaws: it is very clumsy, hard to read and violates the [*no side effects* principle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html):

> Side-effects in behavioral parameters to stream operations are, in general, discouraged, as they can often lead to unwitting violations of the statelessness requirement, as well as other thread-safety hazards.

Compare it with the traditional, procedural and for-loop based solution which is more suitable for this kind of processing:

```
final Map<String, List<String>> map = new HashMap<>();
String lastKey = null;
for (String item: list) {
    if (item.startsWith("src")) {
        map.putIfAbsent(item, new ArrayList<>());
        lastKey = item;
    } else {
        map.get(lastKey).add(item);
    }
}
```

You asked:

> I'm looking for an optimized solution using Java Streams

All I can answer: First think of any working solution, then make it maintainable and readable for the other developer. Lastly, think of the efficiency and performance.